# How can I keep the number pad always appear in uiview?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an uivivewcontroller which I want the number pad always appear like this.[image: square]

How can I make that? Plus, why the upper view which looks like a uitableviewcontroller seems unscrollable? Is that not a uitableview, how can it be made? All in all, I'd like to make a view which looks very similar to this page. What approach is best for me? add subview?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your screen to looks like that page, the easiest way is just to design your screen in IB with the the navigation bar, image, button and all. Then, add your text field and called

```
yourTextField.setDelegate = self;
     yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
     [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

In any `UITextField` you use on your `UIViewController`, just call `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];`